# too many parameters specified for RAISE

Tags: postgresql, raiserror

I'am stuck with the error too many parameters specified for RAISE for the below RAISE specified. I don't find any syntactical problem though.

```
  l_task_source_id:= adapter.array_search('prps',g_status.ip_source_tables);
  l_check_stmt := ' select max(stufe::numeric) from '  || g_status.source_tables[l_task_source_id] ;
  execute     l_check_stmt   into l_max_hierarchy_level;  
  raise notice ' Max  hierarchy level : %',l_max_hierarchy_level;
```

Comment: howyou declare l_max_hierarchy_level?..

Comment: l_max_hierarchy_level integer;

Comment: please post whole sorce and exact whole exception message